# ドメインを入力するとテスト画面ではなくトップページを表示させる方法

Tags: apache

## 質問内容

ドメインを入力すると Apache のテスト画面が表示されるのですがドメインをクリックすると指定した`.php`ファイルがトップページとして表示してほしい(ツイッター等で`twitter.com`と入力すると`twitter/home`画面が表示される)のですがこれをするにはどうしたらいいのでしょうか？下記はテスト画面を非表示する設定ですがちょっとやりたいこととは違います。

参考サイト：
[Apache の初期テストページを表示させないようにする (CentOS 5.4)](https://ez-net.jp/article/FE/R7AcIOxN/HrShOlAee1xv/)
[Apacheのテストページを非表示にする](https://butterbull.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/06/20/003555)
[Apacheのデフォルトページを無効にする](https://zibunlog.com/it/apache-defpage-disable/)

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

テストページが表示されるのは、デフォルトページの設定がされていないからだと思われます。

Apacheファイルパス/conf/httpd.conf　というファイルに、次の行を追加してみてください。

> ```
> DirectoryIndex "指定した.phpファイル"
> ```

そうすれば、"指定した.phpファイル"の内容が表示されるはずです。

apacheが、設定(httpd.conf)を読み込むのは起動時のみなので、httpd.conf を修正したら、必ずapacheを再起動した後に、動作の確認をしてください。